# forbidden 403 http error while sending valid JWT token with each request to Node web server

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, jwt, http-status-code-403

The application has an inlog component, while logging in I get a JWT token.
This token is saved well in the LocalStorage. I can see that in the browser:

I use angular-jwt ("@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.0") and configurated in mij app.module.ts:

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return localStorage.getItem("schoolsysteem");
    },
    headerName: 'Authorization',
    authScheme: 'Bearer ',
    whitelistedDomains: ["localhost:3000/*"],
    blacklistedRoutes: [""]
  }
})
```

The headerName and authScheme are the same as the default values. In fact, this configuration takes care for adding an Authorization header with the token with each request.

An example of the client request is:

```
const subjectJsonArr = '{"name":"'+vakParam.name+'"}';//,"tabs":"'+vakParam.tabs+'"}';

this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:3000/addSubject`, JSON.parse(subjectJsonArr)).subscribe((val) => { //more code }
```

The server side code on NodeJs in /routes/addSubject.js

```
    module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/addSubject', function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => { 
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(req.valueOf());
      if (info !== undefined) {
        console.error(info.message);
        res.status(403).send(info.message);
      } else {
        req.logIn(user, error => {
          const data = {
            name: req.body.name
          };
          console.log('data: '+data);
          User.findOne({
            where: {
              name: data.name,
            },
          }).then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            user
              .update({
                name: data.name
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log('subject created in db');
                res.status(200).send({ message: 'subject created' });
              });
          });
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
};
```

This is the error info in the browser console (Chrome v75):

Here the code of the auth. part in Node:

```
passport.use(
  'addSubject',
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true,
      session: false,
    },
    (req, username, password, done) => {
      console.log('name: '+req.body.name);
      try {
        User.findOne({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                username,
              },
              { email: req.body.email },
            ],
          },
        }).then(user => {
          if (user != null) {
            console.log('username or email already taken');
            return done(null, false, {
              message: 'username or email already taken',
            });
          }
          bcrypt.hash(password, BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS).then(hashedPassword => {
            User.create({
              username,
              password: hashedPassword,
              email: req.body.email,
              role: req.body.role,
              firstName: req.body.firstName,
              lastName: req.body.lastName
            }).then(user => {
              console.log('user created');
              return done(null, user);
            });
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
    },
  ),
);

const opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('schoolsysteem'),
  secretOrKey: jwtSecret.secret,
};

passport.use(
  'jwt',
  new JWTstrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    try {
      User.findOne({
        where: {
          id: jwt_payload.id,
        },
      }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('user found in db in passport');
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          console.log('user not found in db');
          done(null, false);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  }),
);
```

Can someone see what is the cause of the 403 error?
Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be if(err !== undefined ) else ?

Comment: the info is filled with error info ('no auth token'), it won't change the outcome.